# getting controller properties from Ember.Textfield child class

Tags: ember.js

How do I get properties defined in the application controller (or any other controllers) from a function inside a class that extends Ember.TextField?

For example:

```
App.StratsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ({
    dateLimits: [
         {'SPX': ['8/1/2000', '9/3/2013']},
         {'INDU': ['9/1/2000', '10/3/2013']}]
});

App.CustomField = Ember.TextField.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      // need to access dateLimits in here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass them in when you create the custom field

```
{{view App.CustomField dateLimits=dateLimits}}

App.CustomField = Ember.TextField.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      console.log(this.get('dateLimits'));
   }
});
```

Or if it lives on another controller, just add a needs for the controller you need, and access it using `controllers.othercontroller.property`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aVoNoyip/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did the exact same thing in my real program as illustrated in your example, and encountered a very strange proglem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did the exact same thing in my real program as illustrated in your example, and encountered a very strange problem.

In your example, I can do: console.log(this.get('dateLimits')[0].SPX[0]);

In my program, console.log(this.get('dateLimits')) works fine; it  prints out [Object{SPX=[2]},[oBJECT{indu=[2]}].  But if I did: console.log(this.get('dateLimits')[0]), I get: TypeError:this.get(...)is undefined.

What do you think may be causing this?

Comment: What's the context of this in your program?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what to look for in order to answer your question.  I put a break point in firebug on the statement that caused the error, and looked at "this."  There's a bunch of stuff under it.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking; the "context" field under "this" shows undefined.  But this.get('dateLimits') works fine.

Comment: what's `this`  console.log(this)

Comment: console.log(this) shows:
<App.Customfield:ember339>{ valueBinding={...}, dateLimitsBinding={...}, templateData={...}, more...}

There's a lot of stuff underneath if I expand.  Anything in specific I should look for?

This program gets data from a server (server written in Erlang), so not too easy to put into jfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: I started pairing down the function to send to you.  I got to a point where everything worked fine.  So I started adding back the stuff I took off incrementally, hoping to find the exact code that breaks the system.  For some unknown reason, I was able to add back everything I took off, and the system still works.  I'm completely puzzled, and have no clue what happened.  Everything seems to work as expected now; exactly like your sample.  It's really weird.